# Choosing different amount of elements from each group in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am working on the Kaggle Instacart competition, but I am quite new to R and have run into something I can not figure out.

I have a dataset with 4 columns. The first column is an order ID (id1). The second column is a product ID (id2). The third column is the probability that I want select the product id2 from the order id1 which we can consider just as a ranking, so a higher probability is always selected over a smaller probability. Finally, the fourth column is the amount of products I want to select from the given order (a feature of the order). So for example, I have here the first 12 rows of the dataframe df:

```
        id1        id2       prob       num
1        17      13107   0.4756982        3
2        17      21463   0.3724126        3
3        17      38777   0.3534422        3
4        17      21709   0.3364623        3
5        17      47766   0.3364623        3
6        17      39275   0.3165896        3
7        34      16083   0.4093785        4
8        34      39475   0.3892882        4
9        34      47766   0.3892882        4
10       34       2596   0.3837562        4
11       34      21137   0.3762758        4
12       34      47792   0.3737032        4
```

We can see that from the id1 = 17 I want to choose 3 elements, and for id1 = 34 I want to choose 4 elements. The result should then be

```
ID1     ID2
 17     13107, 21463, 38777
 34     16083, 39475, 47766, 2596
```

or something similar to this.

At the moment I have tried using

```
df %>% group_by(id1) %>% top_n(n = num)
```

but I get the error

```
Selecting by num
Error in is_scalar_integerish(n) : object 'num' not found
```

Anyone know how I would go about doing this?

Thanks

Comment: You already have your answer but so you know, `top_n` only takes scalars as input. You also need to define which variable you want to be ranked in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pipe the grouped data directly into a `summarise` statement:

```
df %>% group_by(id1) %>% summarise(id2 = toString(id2[seq_len(first(num))]))
## A tibble: 2 x 2
#    id1                       id2
#  <int>                     <chr>
#1    17       13107, 21463, 38777
#2    34 16083, 39475, 47766, 2596
```

In this statement, the `id2[seq_len(first(num))]` is used to extract the first `num` per group, create a sequence from 1 to the `num` and that sequence is used to subset the first X `id2` values.

The `toString` creates a string per id1 group.

---

Here's another base R option using `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(id2 ~ id1, FUN=toString, subset(df, ave(id1, id1, FUN=seq_along) <= num))
#  id1                       id2
#1  17       13107, 21463, 38777
#2  34 16083, 39475, 47766, 2596
```

---

Please note that I assumed the data was already orderd (as in the example) by decreasing probability.

Comment: Don't you assume in your answer that data is ordered based on probability?

Answer (score 2):

In base R, you can use `Map` on the list of data frames split by ID with `split` to apply `head` to select the respective number of rows for each ID. The number of selected rows is supplied by feeding `tapply` the column of interest and selecting the first value with `head`. A data.frame with the corresponding rows is returned using `do.call` with `rbind`.

```
do.call(rbind, Map(head, split(dat, dat$id1), tapply(dat$num, dat$id1, head, 1)))
      id1   id2      prob num
17.1   17 13107 0.4756982   3
17.2   17 21463 0.3724126   3
17.3   17 38777 0.3534422   3
34.7   34 16083 0.4093785   4
34.8   34 39475 0.3892882   4
34.9   34 47766 0.3892882   4
34.10  34  2596 0.3837562   4
```

It is a bit simpler to return a named list of the first dat$num elements where then names in the list correspond to the id1.

```
Map(head, split(dat$id2, dat$id1), tapply(dat$num, dat$id1, head, 1))
$`17`
[1] 13107 21463 38777

$`34`
[1] 16083 39475 47766  2596
```

**data**

```
dat <-
structure(list(id1 = c(17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 34L, 34L, 
34L, 34L, 34L, 34L), id2 = c(13107L, 21463L, 38777L, 21709L, 
47766L, 39275L, 16083L, 39475L, 47766L, 2596L, 21137L, 47792L
), prob = c(0.4756982, 0.3724126, 0.3534422, 0.3364623, 0.3364623, 
0.3165896, 0.4093785, 0.3892882, 0.3892882, 0.3837562, 0.3762758, 
0.3737032), num = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L)), .Names = c("id1", "id2", "prob", "num"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, good code. Went with docendo discimus suggestion due to the output being on a better format for my given task but your solution works just as well in general!

Answer (score 2):

Having one row per ID may seem nice, but a list column often ends up being a pain to work with; it's not "tidy."  Here's a simple `dplyr` pipeline that sticks to the verbs that make sense: separate by group, filter rows, put back together.

```
df %>%
  group_by(id1) %>%
  filter(seq_along(num) <= num) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(id1, id2)

# A tibble: 7 x 2
    id1   id2
  <int> <int>
1    17 13107
2    17 21463
3    17 38777
4    34 16083
5    34 39475
6    34 47766
7    34  2596
```

Comment: @d.b That would still return a row when `num` is zero for a group.  Use `seq_len(num[[1]])`.

Comment: This is very well working code. In my case I want to write a .csv file right after but I think in many cases this code will work better I guess. Since the already accepted answer gave the output I requested I will keep it as the accepted answer as it seems fairer but I like this solution a lot too

Comment: @d-b I'm fine with his choice.  The other answer gives him the output he requested, and mine gives him the output I thought would be better.  But since he's writing to a CSV, the requested way could be the right choice.  I'm just glad my answer's useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this by using @lmo's data

```
dat%>%group_by(id1)%>%arrange(-prob)%>%dplyr::summarise(ID2=paste(id2[1:unique(num)],collapse=","))
```

Comment: Add `arrange(-prob)` to your answer. Do not assume that the data is ordered.

Answer (score 0):

With `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[order(-prob), .(id2 = toString(head(id2, first(num)))), by = id1]
```

> ```
>    id1                       id2
> 1:  17       13107, 21463, 38777
> 2:  34 16083, 39475, 47766, 2596
> ```

Here, `df` is coerced to `data.table`, ordered by decreasing probability. For each group in `id1`, the `num` topmost values are picked and aggregated into one string.

This returns `id2` as character. If it is required to continue processing, it might be useful to keep the `id2` values separate in a list:

```
setDT(df)[order(-prob), .(id2 = list(head(id2, first(num)))), by = id1]
```

#### Data

```
df <- fread(
"rn        id1        id2       prob       num
1        17      13107   0.4756982        3
2        17      21463   0.3724126        3
3        17      38777   0.3534422        3
4        17      21709   0.3364623        3
5        17      47766   0.3364623        3
6        17      39275   0.3165896        3
7        34      16083   0.4093785        4
8        34      39475   0.3892882        4
9        34      47766   0.3892882        4
10       34       2596   0.3837562        4
11       34      21137   0.3762758        4
12       34      47792   0.3737032        4")
```